# iptables block INPUT port 80

Tags: iptables

My question is for general understanding and not for fixing an issue that I have.

I managed to run `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT` and block http requests. When I ran `curl http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js` I've got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to b.scorecardresearch.com port 80: Connection refused`

Then I deleted the OUTPUT rule and created an INPUT rule `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REJECT`. I could then access `curl http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js` with no problems at all.

I understand why the outgoing request was not blocked but when I make an http request, doesn't the response return on the same port (80) and should be blocked by the INPUT REJECT of port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a TCP connection, the client port is random and different than the destination port (80 here). You can see that by running: `netstat -pant` in your terminal:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.41:39878      201.15.39.91:80        ESTABLISHED 2270/firefox
```

That's why blocking the incoming packets that target port 80 doesn't forbid you to reach HTTP servers. However, if you have an HTTP server, it won't be accessible anymore on port 80.

Comment: So why when I create a TCP connection for ssh on port 22, the outgoing and incoming packets are transmitted on the same port (22) and not on a random port?

Comment: No, that's the same, the packets are transmitted to port 22 but received on a client port on your machine that was generated why you created the connection.